# How to execute script inside or alongside a Jar file?

Tags: java, file, jar, scripting, edit

I have a script that generates 2 new files as tokens and uses them to be authenticate to perform a task. It also has two additional files where it reads information from one text file and inserts it into another JSON file.

So I've got...

- 2 token files
- 1 script file
- 1 text file
- 1 json file

In my local program, I can execute and the script will run fine. It'll search my resources folder, find these 4 files, and use them to perform the task without issue. However when I deploy this program for testing on my backend external server, the program reports it can no longer find these files in the resource directory.

From what I can tell, when it compiles into a jar file, the directory I'm having it search for is no longer valid

The directory changes to...

- /Deployments
- --Data
- --project.jar

My code to find the resources file is as so:

```
private final String scriptPath = "/src/main/resources/";

public void runScript4() {

    String script = "hello.bat";
    try {
        String result = null;
        Process awk = new ProcessBuilder( scriptPath + script).start();
        awk.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Script executing...");
        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(awk.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            result += inputLine;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And locally it'll go to src/main/resources to get the script and use the other files found in that same directory but that doesnt work when it gets deployed and built into a jar.

What's the best approach to get this script executed when deployed online? Is there a way to get a script to create new files in a jar as well as edit existing txt/JSON files? Or is another approach recommended?

Comment: Batch files can not be executed. You always have to execute `cmd.exe` and pass the batch file as argument. Search Stackoverflow for more details how to execute a batch file from Java.

Comment: If your script is really just running awk, you don’t need an external process at all.  Java has a java.util.regex package which can do everything awk can do.

Answer (score 0):

`"/src/main/resources/";` - why would there be a "src" dir when you deploy your app? There is no file **at all** (there is an entry in a jar file. That is not a file!).

Windows cannot look inside jar files (that would be rather bizarre if it could!).

Thus, you need to answer two separate questions:

- How do I read a resource that is inside my jar file?
- How do I write a file to a temp dir so I can then point windows cmd at it?

You have to do this (basically, 'extract that bat file from your own jar, like a mini installer') - because it's either that, or write your own all-java cmd.exe variant that knows how to read and execute bat files. Because windows's `cmd.exe` has no idea how to execute a bat file **inside** of a jar (jar? What's jar? - why would windows know what that is?)

Both of these are easy enough to combine:

```
var tempFile = Files.createTempFile("hello", ".bat");
try (var in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/hello.bat")) {
  Files.copy(in, tempFile);
}

// now run processbuilder and point it at tempFile.
```

Comment: No need for `var out`.  One can just use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...))(in, tempFile).

Comment: Ah, even simpler. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Java jar files are just zip files with some special entries, and if you rename one (or a copy) Windows since Vista can access a zip file as a virtual subtree in explorer; however the OS and thus most programs cannot directly access the entries (unlike Java's ClassLoader or ZipFileSystem) so if you doubleclick a 'file' that is otherwise executable or openable it is automatically extracted to a temp file in the real file system and that is executed or opened instead. And powershell can unpack (all) entries to files, and add files to a (new or existing) zip.